# Why I cannot assign my sass variables in my file system?

Tags: sass

I am practicing sass in my code editor. When I tried to compile my sass file and built a watcher. I receive:

```
Jiatongs-MacBook-Pro:6_myLandingPage_starter jiatongli$ sass --watch sass:css
Error: Undefined variable.
  background-color: $white
                    ^^^^^^
  sass/modules/_navbar.sass 3:21      @import
  sass/modules/_modules-dir.sass 1:9  @import
  sass/app.sass 3:9                   root stylesheet
```

Because I cannoStackOverflow files here on stackoverflow, I link my github repository which is:

https://github.com/riederleeDEV/SASS-project.git.

> It seems like the sass watcher cannot capture my file import and I do
>   not know where went wrong

```
Here is the command I used: sass --watch SASS:CSS(the command should not have any error)
```

After I checked the file, I discovered that there is nothing wrong with my app.sass import nor the typo. Just want to ask where I went wrong?

Comment: I think its happening because you are using a variable just above the sass @import file which is you using. Use your code just after you are calling the sass files.

Comment: Thank you so much Harden! Sorry I did not get it...Can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
                             <····  Move variables to top   
@import "base/base-dir"          |
@import "layout/layout-dir"      |
@import "modules/modules-dir"    |
                                 |
@import "variables"  ············
@import "mixins.sass"
```

Comment: And move Mixins to under the variables at the top as well